# Shopify: Section API not returning blocks added via customise

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api, shopify-template

We are using section rendering API from Shopify here to replace the product blocks dynamically.

Section Rendering API here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering

The sections seem to be rendering fine, but it doesn't render any blocks added to the section schema.

Can you please suggest, what's going wrong here?

Section schema:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Reviews",
    "class": "review-slider",
    "settings": [
     {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable",
      "label": "Uncheck to hide the section",
      "default": true
    },
    ],
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "Review",
        "settings": [ 
          {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "username",
            "label": "User Name"
          },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "review",
            "label": "Review"
          },

        {
      "type": "url",
      "id": "link",
      "label": "Add link"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "btntext",
      "label": "Button Label"
    }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "presets": [
        {
            "name": "Review Slider"
        }
    ]
  }
```

The API call: GET request to /products/<product_url>/?sections=review-slider

Comment: what data you currently get when make this call?

Comment: everything ( product data, variants ) but not section blocks, they are blank

Comment: okay, I think the issue is with your request, you need to pass the section Id to request and it seems you pass the class that added into schema, so can you check the `{{section.id}}` output on frontend and pass the correct ID.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qdElzveBtnzL

Comment: @Onkar no thats not the case we are passing the correct section id

Comment: @user2119554 https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering#find-section-ids read the docs man